# what is the steps to run java class makes connection with hbase?

Tags: java, connection, hbase

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HTable table = new HTable(config, "myLittleHBaseTable");
```

then i get this error after creating the admin

> Opening socket connection to server Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

Answer (score 0):

This is a screenshot of the list of jars in my project which successfully writes and reads to and from HBase:

[image: jars required to connect hbase]

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846243/how-to-get-timestamped-versions-of-hbase-cell), I asked how to get multiple versions of one timestamped cell. That code is below. It totally works for creating a table, inserting a value, and retrieving a value.

Regarding your question exactly, I think you need to add more information to your config portion of code such as ...

```
    //config
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.clear();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_IP);
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_PROPERTY_CLIENTPORT);
    config.set("hbase.master", HBASE_MASTER);
```

... where the values of those capitalized variables can be seen in the full code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws ZooKeeperConnectionException, MasterNotRunningException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    final String HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_IP = "localhost.localdomain"; //set ip in hosts file
    final String HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_PROPERTY_CLIENTPORT = "2181";
    final String HBASE_MASTER = HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_IP + ":60010";

    //identify a data cell with these properties
    String tablename = "characters";
    String row = "johnsmith";
    String family = "capital";
    String qualifier = "A"; 

    //config
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.clear();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_IP);
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_PROPERTY_CLIENTPORT);
    config.set("hbase.master", HBASE_MASTER);

    //admin
    HBaseAdmin hba = new HBaseAdmin(config);

    //create a table
    HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor(tablename);
    descriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(family));
    hba.createTable(descriptor);
    hba.close();

    //get the table
    HTable htable = new HTable(config, tablename);

    //insert 10 different timestamps into 1 record
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String value = Integer.toString(i);
        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier), System.currentTimeMillis(), Bytes.toBytes(value));
        htable.put(put);
        Thread.sleep(200); //make sure each timestamp is different
    }

    //get 10 timestamp versions of 1 record
    final int MAX_VERSIONS = 10;
    Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(row));
    get.setMaxVersions(MAX_VERSIONS);
    Result result = htable.get(get);
    byte[] value = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier));  // returns MAX_VERSIONS quantity of values
    String output = Bytes.toString(value);

    //show me what you got
    System.out.println(output); //prints 9 instead of 0 through 9
}
```

Comment: that was helpful 
but mongodb was a better choice than hbase

Answer (score -1):

Do you have hbase-site.xml in your java classpath? HBase get zookeeper information from hbas-site.xml and connect to zookeeper and then you are connect HBase.

Comment: I think my answer is right answer. You could ignore this error "Opening socket connection to server Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)". But you should set "zookeeper.znode.parent", "hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hbase.zookeeper.clientPort" in your HBase Configuration.