# How to get timestamped versions of HBase cell

Tags: java, hbase

How do I return all timestamped versions of an HBase cell with the Get.setMaxVersions(10) method where 10 is an arbitrary number (could be something else like 20 or 5)? The following is a console main method that creates a table, inserts 10 random integers, and tries to retrieve all of them to print out.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws ZooKeeperConnectionException, MasterNotRunningException, IOException, InterruptedException {

final String HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_IP = "localhost.localdomain"; //set ip in hosts file
final String HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_PROPERTY_CLIENTPORT = "2181";
final String HBASE_MASTER = HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_IP + ":60010";

//identify a data cell with these properties
String tablename = "characters";
String row = "johnsmith";
String family = "capital";
String qualifier = "A"; 

//config
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.clear();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_IP);
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_PROPERTY_CLIENTPORT);
config.set("hbase.master", HBASE_MASTER);

//admin
HBaseAdmin hba = new HBaseAdmin(config);

//create a table
HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor(tablename);
descriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(family));
hba.createTable(descriptor);
hba.close();

//get the table
HTable htable = new HTable(config, tablename);

//insert 10 different timestamps into 1 record
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String value = Integer.toString(i);
    Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row));
    put.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier), System.currentTimeMillis(), Bytes.toBytes(value));
    htable.put(put);
    Thread.sleep(200); //make sure each timestamp is different
}

//get 10 timestamp versions of 1 record
final int MAX_VERSIONS = 10;
Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(row));
get.setMaxVersions(MAX_VERSIONS);
Result result = htable.get(get);
byte[] value = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier));  // returns MAX_VERSIONS quantity of values
String output = Bytes.toString(value);

//show me what you got
System.out.println(output); //prints 9 instead of 0 through 9
}
```

The output is 9 (because the loop ended at i=9, and I don't see multiple versions in Hue's HBase Browser web UI. What can I do to fix the versions so it gives me 10 individual results for 0 - 9 instead of one result of only the number 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [getColumnCells](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getColumnCells(byte[],%20byte[])) on Result to get all versions (depending on MAX_VERSION_COUNT you have set in Get). [getValue](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getValue(byte[],%20byte[])) returns the latest value.

Sample Code:

```
    List<Cell> values = result.getColumnCells(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier));
    for ( Cell cell : values )
    {
        System.out.println( Bytes.toString( CellUtil.cloneValue( cell ) ) );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Kapil. You pointed me in the right direction. My version of HBase uses older deprecated methods. I'll include the code that got working based on the API you shared with me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a deprecated approach which matches the version of HBase I am currently working on.

```
List<KeyValue> kvpairs = result.getColumn(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier));
String line = "";
for(KeyValue kv : kvpairs) {
    line += Bytes.toString(kv.getValue()) + "\n";
}
System.out.println(line);
```

Then, going one step further, it is important to note the setMaxVersions method must be called at table creation to allow for more than a default three values to be inserted into a cell. Here's the updated table creation:

```
//create a table based on variables from question above
HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(tablename);
HColumnDescriptor columnDescriptor = new HColumnDescriptor(columnFamily);
columnDescriptor.setMaxVersions(MAX_VERSIONS);
tableDescriptor.addFamily(columnDescriptor);
hba.createTable(tableDescriptor);
hba.close();
```