# Hbase extracting value and timestamp from a cell

Tags: java, hbase

In hbase I have number of columns: name, city,...
Not all columns have values ( some rows can have only 'name' for example)

I want to extract all columns in a row + timestamp of column (in specific order), in case value is null I want to return empty string.

The problem that I facing, I must access column in `Result` by 'family' and 'qualifier' (I can't access by index of `result.listCells().get(i)` because null values are skipped)

```
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("personal data"), Bytes.toBytes("name"));
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("personal data"), Bytes.toBytes("city"));

ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);

for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner.next()){

    byte [] valCity = result.getValue("personal data", "city"); //can't get timestamp using this
  //check if valCity null write ("") else write the value
  //next column... 
}
```

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846243/how-to-get-timestamped-versions-of-hbase-cell hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a CellScanner for this. See example below:

```java
    CellScanner cellScanner = result.cellScanner();
    while (cellScanner.advance()) {
        Cell cell = cellScanner.current();
        byte[] columnName = Bytes.copy(cell.getQualifierArray(),
                cell.getQualifierOffset(),
                cell.getQualifierLength());
        byte[] familyName = Bytes.copy(cell.getFamilyArray(),
                cell.getFamilyOffset(),
                cell.getFamilyLength());
        long timestamp = cell.getTimestamp();
        .....
    }
```

Comment: I guess searching for the right column using this is not efficient,  as i will need to loop scanner each time I search for a right column name.
in case I need to extract column in specific order.

Comment: Hmm you write in your question what you want to get all columns. You can remeber column namve, timestamps and values and sort them as you need.

Comment: to get all columns in specific order. this why i wanted to use `result.getValue("personal data", "city");` this allows me to access by name  I also don't see a real difference between scanner and  `result.listCells().get(i)`